# Зацикленность запросов двух одинаковых таблиц

Tags: spring, jpa

У меня есть две сущности:

```
class User {
    @Id
    Integer id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    Device device;
}

class Device {
    @Id
    Integer id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "dock")
    User user;
}
```

И RestController:

```
class Rest {
    @GetMapping
    public String get {
        return userRepo.getOne(); // возвращает одного пользователя.
    }
}
```

Соответственно, две таблицы начинают друг на друга ссылаться. Если добавлять `@JsonIgnore`, то, соответственно, в одной из таблиц я что-то не дополучу.

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы это "взаимное обращение" останавливалось на первом "проходе"?

Comment: https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonManagedReference.html

Comment: http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion